# Rest calls from python script Kubeflow pipeline

Tags: python, python-requests, kubeflow-pipelines

I am using kubeflow pipelines rest API in order to initiate a new run for an existing pipeline in kubeflow pipelines, and I keep getting an error when using the API with POST requests. Here is a sample of my code - I have already authenticated myself with a requests session, and I'm using the python requests package to do the POST/GET requests. I've replaced the pipeline and experiment ID with $experimentID and $pipelineid

```
runURL = f"{HOST}/pipeline/apis/v1beta1/runs"
inputobject2={"description":"","name":"gcd_test3","pipeline_spec":
{"parameters":[{"name":"a","value":"70"},{"name":"b","value":"35"},{"name":"c","value":"42"},{"name":"d","value":"14"}]},
"resource_references":[{"key":{"id":"$experimentID","type":"EXPERIMENT"},"relationship":"OWNER"},
{"key":{"id":"$pipelineid","type":"PIPELINE_VERSION"},"relationship":"CREATOR"}],"service_account":""}
headers2 = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
output = session.post(runURL, data=inputobject2, headers = headers2)
pp.pprint(output)
pp.pprint(output.json())
```

The printed output for this is

```
<Response [400]>
{'code': 3,
 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/api.Error',
              'error_details': 'Invalid input error: ListRuns must filter by '
                               'resource reference in multi-user mode.',
              'error_message': 'ListRuns must filter by resource reference in '
                               'multi-user mode.'}],
 'error': 'Invalid input error: ListRuns must filter by resource reference in '
          'multi-user mode.',
 'message': 'Invalid input error: ListRuns must filter by resource reference '
            'in multi-user mode.'}
```

I only get this output for POST requests, while GET requests work perfectly fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the exact same problem and the documentation doesn't mention how to define the namespace. I am making the request using cURL.

From all the requests the Kubeflow API documentation presents (https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/reference/api/kubeflow-pipeline-api-spec/), the only one that works is when I request all experiments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the namespace is missing, which seems to be required in multi-user environments.

Please keep in mind, that you could use the Python SDK [1] for creating runs  [2].

[1] https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/tutorials/sdk-examples/

[2] https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/tools/benchmarks/run_service_api.ipynb